# ng2-smart-table how to change custom button show and hide on click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

i have play and start custom button. When i click on play icon Stop icon should be visible and play icon should be hide for row where i clicked.

```html
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (userRowSelect)="AdapInformation($event)"  (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteAdap($event)">
```

```html
settings = {
    
   actions: {
  columnTitle: 'Action',
  position: 'right',
  add: false,
    
       edit:false,
    custom: [
        { name: 'startAdaptor', title: '<i class="startAdded nb-play nbPlayIcon ng2-smart-actions"></i>' },
        { name: 'stopAdaptor', title: '<i class="stopAdded nb-square ng2-smart-actions"></i>' },
        { name: 'editAdaptor', title: '<i class="nb-edit nbeditStyle ng2-smart-actions"></i>' }

    ],
 },
  .....
  
  }
```

how to solved ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to do this would be with a **custom component**. You can specify a column where the component will be rendered on each row and encapsulate the play/stop behavior in this component.

First, **create a custom component**, for example `MediaControlComponent`:

```
@Component({
selector: 'ngx-media-control',
template: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClick()">
    <i *ngIf="!isPlaying" class="nb-play"></i>
    <i *ngIf="isPlaying" class="nb-square"></i></a>`,
})
export class MediaControlComponent implements OnInit {
    public isPlaying: boolean;
    public renderValue: string;

    @Input() value: string | number;
    @Input() rowData: any;

    @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
    }

    onClick() {
        this.isPlaying = this.isPlaying ? false : true;
        this.save.emit(this.rowData);
    }
}
```

Make sure you **add this component in your module**, both in `imports` and `entryComponents`.

Then, in your ng2-smart-table **settings**, add a **column**:

```
mediaControl: {
    title: 'mediaControl',
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: MediaControlComponent,
    onComponentInitFunction: (instance: any) => {
        instance.save.subscribe(row => {
            // Do something (you have the row information in the `row` variable).
        });
    }
},
```

**That's it!** You'll have the behavior you want for the play/stop button, as well as a way to make something happen when the play/stop button is clicked.

*Note: I am not rendering the custom component in the `action` part of ng2-smart-table settings due to it not working when I tried it (I am rendering it in a column instead). If you can make it work, go ahead.*